# MariaDB: behavior on different time ranges

Tags: sql, mariadb

I'm observing a strange behavior on a particular query executed on MariaDB (v10.6.12), and I'm not able to explain that.

The table is created as:

```
CREATE TABLE `mytable` 
(
    `meter_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `value` double NOT NULL,
    `datetime` datetime NOT NULL,
    KEY `mytable_meter_id_datetime_index` (`meter_id`,`datetime`),
    CONSTRAINT `mytable_meter_id_foreign` 
        FOREIGN KEY (`meter_id`) REFERENCES `meters` (`id`) 
             ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Now I'm comparing those two EXPLAINs, where the same query is executed with a different dates range: 3 months Vs 1 month.

```
explain select sum(`value`) as aggregate from `mytable` where `meter_id` in (...) and `datetime` >= '2023-06-05 00:00:00' and `datetime` < '2023-09-05 00:00:00';
+------+-------------+---------+------+---------------------------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table   | type | possible_keys                   | key  | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra       |
+------+-------------+---------+------+---------------------------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | mytable | ALL  | mytable_meter_id_datetime_index | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 3061656 | Using where |
+------+-------------+---------+------+---------------------------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
```

```
explain select sum(`value`) as aggregate from `mytable` where `meter_id` in (...) and `datetime` >= '2023-06-05 00:00:00' and `datetime` < '2023-07-05 00:00:00';
+------+-------------+---------+-------+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------+------+--------+-----------------------+
| id   | select_type | table   | type  | possible_keys                   | key                             | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra                 |
+------+-------------+---------+-------+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------+------+--------+-----------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | mytable | range | mytable_meter_id_datetime_index | mytable_meter_id_datetime_index | 13      | NULL | 384057 | Using index condition |
+------+-------------+---------+-------+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------+------+--------+-----------------------+
```

The second one leverages the INDEX on `meter_id` and `datetime`, the first one does not. And executing three different queries, one for each month in the desired range, is a lot faster then querying once the 3-months range.

What may cause this (in particular the INDEX activation on the second query)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a general assumption that when using an index for more than a portion of it (somewhere around 20% but I haven't found an exact reference), its more efficient to not use an index.

Your one month query, the second one, is using 12.5% of rows (384057/3061656), where assuming a linear dataset, 3 months is going to be 37.6%, which is why its not used.

option 1: [FORCE INDEX](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/index-hints-how-to-force-query-plans/#force-index-forcing-an-index), then the query becomes:

```
... from `mytable` FORCE INDEX mytable_meter_id_datetime_index where ...
```

option 2: append `value` to the index

This allows the query to ["Using index"](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/explain/) and avoids a second lookup to retrieve the value.

Putting `meter_id,datetime` as a primary key would have the same performance impact as this. The reverse `meter_id,datetime` is also valid but consider what is queried most and what is more selective in those sorts of queries.

option 3: Add a `datetime,meter_id,value` index

This is on the assumption that a 3 month window is less than the ~20% mark

Detailed information can be found using [analyze format=json](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/analyze-format-json/) or the the [optimizer trace](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/optimizer-trace-guide/).

Comment: @madbob glad you found this useful. Feel free to comment or add another answer on which way you resolved this.